# nginx not showing any subdirectories

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx configuration for one of my sites. Its showing the files in the `/var/www/html/tommiejones` subfolder but its not showing the subdirectories. I have multiple files in the top level directory and its showing those fine.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.tommiejones.com tommiejones.com;

    root /var/www/html/tommiejones;

    location ~/api/(.*)$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/$1;
    }

    location / {
            root /var/www/html/tommiejones;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` directive could be replaced with `autoindex on`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    autoindex on;

    server_name www.tommiejones.com tommiejones.com;
    root /var/www/html/tommiejones;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~/api/(.*)$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/$1;
    }
}
```